# What is the word for giving advice or suggestions to make something better?

Tags: word-choice, american-english, formal-language

I would like to give some advices to a client via email, but I don't know what to write in the subject to make it formal.

I don't know if I should use *advice* or *suggestions* because I think that would be informal, and this client needs to feel respect from me.

Comment: How about _Feedback_?

Comment: We need more context to answer the question. Why are you giving the client suggestions? Did they ask for you to look at something? Did you notice some problems on your own? Did they hire you to give this advice?

Comment: @EsotericScreenName No they did not ask, but i think i discovered some informations might be helpful to them, and i aim to use this opportunity as a chance to improve our relation ship for future purposes. But usually people don't like being given advices, so i need to be very careful here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the word **[recommendation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/recommendation)**: A suggestion or proposal as to the best course of action. Or the word [**guidance**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/guidance) : Advice or information aimed at resolving a problem or difficulty

Comment: Recommendation sounds good to me, i think i'm gonna stick with it, thanks mate